# How to increase startup speed on mozilla firefox?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, browser, freeze, firefox

How to increase startup speed on newest version of mozilla firefox?
it always happened when i opened Mozilla Firefox, it seem like freeze or not responding, and it will take about 15 second to Mozilla runs correctly. Any ideas to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to decrease Firefox load time, remove all addons that you installed on it. All addons must be loaded during the load time and most of them are heavy enough to increase load times by a scale of seconds.

Also, you can find some tutorials that promisses increase Firefox performance. Take a look at these links:

[12 Tricks To Increase Your Firefox Speed By A Noticeable Amount.](http://tutzone.org/increase-firefox-speed-by-10-30x/)

[How To Increase Firefox Page Transfer Speed Up To 40 Percent](http://mostlysavingmoney.com/how-to-increase-firefox-page-transfer-speed-up-to-40-percent/)

[How to Increase FireFox Load time??](http://vakul.wordpress.com/2006/11/15/how-to-increase-firefox-load-time/)

[How to Improve and Speed Up Firefox Start-up Time](http://www.gearfire.net/improve-firefox-start-up-time/)

Comment: The goal should be to "decrease time". :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the startup speed on Mozilla firefox, maybe you can do these steps:

- Defragment your hard drive. (If using Windows, you can found in the Start Menu ---> All
  Programs ---> Accessories ----> System Tools ----> Disk Defragment.
- Remove all the History, Cookies, and Cache, then check the applicable options, or in the
  Mozilla Suite preference ("Advanced -> Cached Web Content, click clear now").
- Clean your bookmarks.

then restart your browser..

Answer (score 0):

**Reduce firefox cold start to warm start time:**

Put an shortcut to firefox in the autostart directory in which you add `-silent` (using Properties of the shortcut), e.g. `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -silent`.

In the case, that you get a recover prompt at the beginning, set `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` in about:config to `false`. (This does not affect your recover ability, e.g. if you use "SessionManager", you can easily restore your last session - but you are not asked automatically; in SessionManager you need to additionally tick `use browser's built in crash recovery prompt`).